# Create R Function with flexibility to reference different datasets

Tags: r, function, naming

I am trying to create a simple function in R that can reference multiple datasets and multiple variable names. Using the following code, I get an error, which I believe is due to referencing:

```
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(x = sample(10), y = sample(10), z = sample(10))
dat2 <- data.frame(x = sample(10), y = sample(10), z = sample(10))

table(dat1$x, dat1$y)
table(dat2$x, dat2$y)

fun <- function(dat, sig, range){print(table(dat$sig, dat$range))}

fun(dat = dat1, sig = x, range =  y)
fun(dat = dat2, sig = x, range =  y)
```

Any idea how to adjust this code so that it can return the table appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[[ ]]` operator on data frame is similar to `$` but allows you to introduce an object and look for it's value. Then outside of the function you assign "`x`" value to `sig`. if you don't put quotes there R will look for `x` object

```
fun <- function(dat, sig, range){print(table(dat[[sig]], dat[[range]]))}

fun(dat = dat1, sig = "x", range =  "y")
fun(dat = dat2, sig = "x", range =  "y")
```

Comment: [[ ]] operator on data frame is similar to $ but allows you to introduce an object and look for it's value. then outside of the function you assign "x" value to sig. if you don't put cuotes there R will look for x object

Comment: Your comment should probably go into the answer itself. Comments are not guaranteed to stick around/not be deleted, so anything important to the conversation should be in the Q and A itself.

Comment: Good comment from @AndriyTkach due to R's not so great scoping decisions. Just to illustrate the point. `r = 1:10; f = function(x, r) {x[r]}` and `f(10:1) vs f(10:1, 10:1)`

Comment: I fail to understand @Vlo's concern. In the first instance `r` is found outside the function and in the second instance with a different argument to R, a different result. Where is the difficulty? I admit to puzzlement that first doing `rm(r)` and then repeating `f(10:1)` is not throwing an error.

Comment: @BondedDust I think the concern is that `r` is an argument to the function, so it should at least warn when it looks for `r` there and fails to find it. I can't figure why `f` works without a second argument here, either; I suspect it's some edge case. Seems the whole thing is very tangential to this Q&A, in any case.

Comment: I found a sentence in the help page `?"["` that I suspect covers this: "An empty index selects all values: this is most often used to replace all the entries but keep the attributes." I think the issue relating to `r` being in the Global environment is bogus. Compare: `r = 1:10; f = function(x, z=NULL) {x[z]} ; f(10:1)  #integer(0)` versus `r = 1:10; f = function(x, z) {x[z]} ; f(10:1)  # [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1`. It's not the scoping issue at all but rather how "[" is defined.

Comment: Thank's for adding a comment to answer for me. I will take it in mind in my future answers